# Images are showing for 1 sec before javascript animation is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-redux, gatsby

I have made a website with gatsby.js. I animate some images with bounce.js, which is a javascript library that animates the DOM.

Everything looks good on my local computer, but when I deployed it to a live server, I have the following problem: The images are supposed to fade in on page load. When I load the website, you can see the images at the position they are supposed to end up in for a second, then disappear and fade in like I want them to.

What might be the reason for the images to appear there for a second? How can I avoid this or circumvent it?

edit:

here's some code:

```
import React from "react"
import Bounce from 'bounce.js'

// Images
import imgBoodlefight from '../img/index_boodlefight.svg'
import imgLogo from '../img/index_logo.svg'
import imgDelivery from '../img/index_delivery.svg'


// Layout
import Left from '../components/Left'
import Right from '../components/Right'
import RightTop from '../components/RightTop'
import RightBottom from '../components/RightBottom'

export default class Home extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var bounceBoodlefight = new Bounce();
    var bounceDelivery = new Bounce();
    var bounceDeliveryTxt = new Bounce();
    var bounceLogo = new Bounce();

    bounceBoodlefight
      .translate({
        from: { x: 0 , y: -400 },
        to: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        duration: 1000,
        stiffness: 1,
        bounces: 0
      })
    .applyTo(document.querySelectorAll(".boodlefight-img"));

    bounceDelivery
      .translate({
        from: { x: 400 , y: 0 },
        to: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        duration: 1000,
        stiffness: 1,
        bounces: 0
      })
      // .scale({
      //   from: { x: 1.2, y: 1.2 },
      //   to: { x: 1, y: 1 },
      //   duration: 10000,
      //   bounces: 13,
      //   stiffness: 1
      // })
      .applyTo(document.querySelectorAll(".delivery-bag"));

    bounceDeliveryTxt
      .translate({
        from: { x: -500 , y: 0 },
        to: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        duration: 1000,
        stiffness: 1,
        bounces: 0
      })
      .applyTo(document.querySelectorAll(".delivery-txt"));

    bounceLogo
      .translate({
        from: { x: 0 , y:  500 },
        to: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        duration: 2000,
        stiffness: 1,
        bounces: 4
      })
      .scale({
        from: { x: 1.2, y: 1.2 },
        to: { x: 1, y: 1 },
        duration: 10000,
        bounces: 10,
        stiffness: 1
      })
      .applyTo(document.querySelectorAll(".logo-img"));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
      <Left> 
      <img className="logo-img" src={imgLogo} alt="Logo" />;
      </Left>

      <Right>

        <RightTop> 
          <img className="boodlefight-img" src={imgBoodlefight} alt="Boodlefight" />;
        </RightTop>

        <RightBottom> 
          <span className="delivery-txt" style={{color: 'lavender', margin: '10px'}}>
            Order for delivery coming soon
          </span> 

          <img className="delivery-bag" src={imgDelivery} alt="Delivery" style={{margin: '10px'}} />
        </RightBottom>

      </Right>

    </div>      
    );
  }

}
```

here the scss I am using:

```
.delivery-bag, .boodlefight-img, .logo-img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Try setting `display:none` css on the images. The animation should take care of changing the display property when it kicks in.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried that, but it does not work, the image is just not showing at all now.

Comment: componentDidMount is calling after the renderer is called and the dom of the renderer is loaded. 
So the image is loaded and than you apply the animation.
Adding opacity:0 or display:none should hide the image.
Than you can show the image in the animation, for example:
from: {opacity: 0}, to: {opacity: 1}

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think bounce.js allows for something like `from: {opacity: 0}, to: {opacity: 1}` - it only takes x & y for the from and to parameters.

Answer (score 1):

One reason could be that the HTML and the image are loaded, than after some time the CSS file is loaded.
So what happens is that the image is shown, than the CSS applies and the animation is played.
One solution could be: 
add display none to the image inline + add to the CSS file display: inline block.

Comment: so on the React Element itself `style={{display:"none"}}` (which would be inline), and then in my css `display: inline-block;` ? If that's correct and that's what you mean, then I've tried that and it did not work.

Comment: @GeorgeWelder if it did not work, then pls show us the code